# jQuery: stopPropagation for link

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can i stop propagation for link?

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $(function() {
        $("#g").click(function(event){
            alert("Link clicked");
            event.stopPropagation();
        });
    });
</script>
<a id="g" href="http://google.com">Google</a>
```

I want the browser don't go to google, just show alert.

Comment: FYI, `stopPropagation` prevents the event from being triggered on parents - that's something quite different.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You have to use `event.preventDefault();` to prevent the default action -navigating to Google- from happening.

Answer (score 4):

You will need `event.preventDefault()` and also return false

Comment: `return false` is a combination of both, so there is never the need for coding both.

Answer (score 2):

if you just want to not go to google, just return false.

```
$("#g").bind('click', function(event){
   alert("Link clicked");
   return false;
});
```